# Display different images for every annotation on mapView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkpinannotationview, mkpointannotation

Working with MapKit and Swift, I am trying to display a number of annotations with each having a unique image to display in the leftCalloutAccessoryView.  I am able to display annotations with different titles and subtitles; however, the image that is displayed for every annotation is the same image - I am having trouble figuring out how to make every image unique.  Much appreciation on any and all feedback/guidance to getting this to work.  Code below (p.s. I am aware I have hard-coded an image; I am unsure how to iterate through each annotation to display the appropriate images):

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mySearch.delegate = self
    theMapView.delegate = self

    var latAustin:CLLocationDegrees = 30.274751
    var lngAustin:CLLocationDegrees = -97.739141

    var latAustinDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.1
    var lngAustinDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.1

    var theSpan:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latAustinDelta, lngAustinDelta)
    var austinLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latAustin, lngAustin)
    var theRegion:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(austinLocation, theSpan)

    theMapView.setRegion(theRegion, animated: true)
    //        println(theMapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    //        println(theMapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)

    for var i = 0; i < politicians.count; i++ {
        var politician = MKPointAnnotation()

        var politicianTotalFunding:String = politicians[i]["totalFunding"]! as String

        politician.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(politiciansCoords[i]["lat"]! as CLLocationDegrees, politiciansCoords[i]["lng"]! as CLLocationDegrees)
        politician.title = politicians[i]["name"]! as String
        politician.subtitle = "Total Funding: \(politicianTotalFunding)"

        theMapView.addAnnotation(politician)
    }
}


// Delegate method called each time an annotation appears in the visible window
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.animatesDrop = true
        pinView!.pinColor = .Red

        var imageview = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 45))
        imageview.image = UIImage(named: politicians[0]["photo"])
        pinView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imageview

        pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton
    } else {
        pinView!.annotation = annotation
    }
    return pinView
}
```

Thanks again so much for all your help!

Comment: In viewForAnnotation, you _could_ iterate through the array to find the politician where name equals annotation.title (or use the `filter` function).  However, a better approach is to create a custom annotation class that includes the photoName and then no iteration or searching at all will be needed in viewForAnnotation (annotation argument will have all the data for the politician within it).

Answer (score 1):

you need to create custom MKPointAnnotation class and then add those annotation . when view is called you can use custom variable defined in MKPointAnnotation as images.